# Glue records/delegations on bind9

Tags: linux, bind

We have an internal root hint server and several nameservers for different domains.
Let's say we have 3 domains with different nameservers `example.com, solo.example.com, dmz.example.com`. So each of the domains have 2 NS records.

My question. Is there a way for me to hint towards `dmz.example.com` and `solo.example.com` while still hinting towards `example.com`? So that if `example.com` is not reachable then `dmz.example.com` and `solo.example.com` could still be reachable.

Example of what the root hints file COULD look like.

```
.      6000              IN    SOA   root.example.com. admin.example.com. (
                               2023071420
                               1D
                               1H
                               1W
                               1D)
                         IN    NS    root.example.com
root.example.com.        IN    A    172.16.1.10

example.com.             IN    NS   ns1.example.com.
example.com.             IN    NS   ns2.example.com.
ns1.example.com.         IN    A    172.16.10.1
ns2.example.com.         IN    A    172.16.10.2

solo.example.com.        IN    NS   ns1.solo.example.com.
solo.example.com.        IN    NS   ns2.solo.example.com.
ns1.solo.example.com.    IN    A    172.16.15.1
ns2.solo.example.com.    IN    A    172.16.15.2

dmz.example.com.        IN    NS   ns1.dmz.example.com.
dmz.example.com.        IN    NS   ns2.dmz.example.com.
ns1.dmz.example.com.    IN    A    172.16.17.1
ns2.dmz.example.com.    IN    A    172.16.17.2
```

Comment: As it turns out there is no solution for this. DNS simply doesn't work this way.